# puppet dashboard upgrade is failing

Tags: puppet

following this page:  Not able to get the latest puppet dashboard installed....
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/manual/1.2/upgrading.html#upgrading-code

Commands typing:

```
git init
rm .gitignore
wget https://raw.github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-dashboard/{version tag}/.gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "conversion commit"
git branch original
git remote add upstream git://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-dashboard.git
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard tags/{version tag}
git merge --no-ff original
git reset --soft tags/{version tag}
git stash save "Non-ignored files which were changed after the original installation."
git checkout tags/v1.2.0
git stash apply
```

Thanks!

```
VB MP > git reset --hard tags/v1.1.0
HEAD is now at e6dec8e Update CHANGELOG for 1.1.0
VB MP > git merge --no-ff original
Auto-merging CHANGELOG
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in CHANGELOG
Auto-merging README.markdown
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.markdown
Auto-merging RELEASE_NOTES.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in RELEASE_NOTES.md
Auto-merging Rakefile
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Rakefile
Auto-merging VERSION
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in VERSION
Auto-merging bin/external_node
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in bin/external_node
Auto-merging config/settings.yml.example
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/settings.yml.example
Auto-merging ext/packaging/debian/changelog
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ext/packaging/debian/changelog
Auto-merging ext/packaging/debian/copyright
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ext/packaging/debian/copyright
Auto-merging ext/packaging/redhat/puppet-dashboard.spec
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ext/packaging/redhat/puppet-dashboard.spec
Auto-merging lib/puppet_https.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/puppet_https.rb
Auto-merging lib/tasks/import_reports.rake
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/tasks/import_reports.rake
Auto-merging lib/tasks/mail_patches.rake
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/tasks/mail_patches.rake
Auto-merging lib/tasks/plugins.rake
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in lib/tasks/plugins.rake
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
VB MP > git reset --soft tags/v1.1.0
fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge.
VB MP > git stash save "Non-ignored files which were changed after the original installation."
CHANGELOG: needs merge
README.markdown: needs merge
RELEASE_NOTES.md: needs merge
Rakefile: needs merge
VERSION: needs merge
bin/external_node: needs merge
config/settings.yml.example: needs merge
ext/packaging/debian/changelog: needs merge
ext/packaging/debian/copyright: needs merge
ext/packaging/redhat/puppet-dashboard.spec: needs merge
lib/puppet_https.rb: needs merge
lib/tasks/import_reports.rake: needs merge
lib/tasks/mail_patches.rake: needs merge
lib/tasks/plugins.rake: needs merge

CHANGELOG: needs merge
README.markdown: needs merge
RELEASE_NOTES.md: needs merge
Rakefile: needs merge
VERSION: needs merge
bin/external_node: needs merge
config/settings.yml.example: needs merge
ext/packaging/debian/changelog: needs merge
ext/packaging/debian/copyright: needs merge
ext/packaging/redhat/puppet-dashboard.spec: needs merge
lib/puppet_https.rb: needs merge
lib/tasks/import_reports.rake: needs merge
lib/tasks/mail_patches.rake: needs merge
lib/tasks/plugins.rake: needs merge
CHANGELOG: unmerged (3939269b985675b1bae481c5df1213c207a2a2e1)
CHANGELOG: unmerged (563e996b994dbdaf8e512f3a9ce786aba42a7c6f)
README.markdown: unmerged (b5d1be8fde057e14c0ebf861327230bf3e1b4ed5)
README.markdown: unmerged (7ba28b4e33fd49a7ba684a82a4062cf70ad4d960)
RELEASE_NOTES.md: unmerged (cb089603793c02a9459a00f7dfe3805c5d6a3259)
RELEASE_NOTES.md: unmerged (1d76112b2d5fd96121b08d0593f226cf03b40aae)
Rakefile: unmerged (3bb0e8592a41ae3185ee32266c860714980dbed7)
Rakefile: unmerged (f9177c11f2cd17971fb7dd1cb5a850a29c2ba820)
VERSION: unmerged (795460fcec8812040dd07965dc70d61d221059c9)
VERSION: unmerged (56130fb3a196dbde484abf6b391a877c97a27e65)
...
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
VB MP > 
VB MP > git checkout tags/v1.2.0
error: pathspec 'tags/v1.2.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
VB MP > git stash apply
No stash found.
VB MP >
```